# Blank screen after logout Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: logout

I have recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 x64 on a 2013 UEFI laptop which was running Win8. Now I only have Ubuntu 13.04.

The distribution is working well in most case. However, a few seconds after I logout, I see a blank screen. After a few seconds, I can hear the dum-dum sound. If I press on my Num Lk key or CapsLk, the light indicator still works.

I cannot suspend either.

I suspect it is a display error, since my laptop has only the 1600x900 res.

Thank you.

Here are some of my specs:
Processor   2x Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU 2020M @ 2.40GHz

Memory  3914MB (1554MB used)

Operating System    Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: Can you please add your graphics card model to the question? Also, open a terminal and provide the output of `lspci`, read [I have a hardware detection problem, what logs do I need to look into?](http://askubuntu.com/q/14008/159545) for more useful information you might provide.

Answer (score 0):

### Since you don't have Grub

***Go for a system test first***. Go to Applications -> System Tools -> Administration -> System Testing and put your password when asked. **Reply with result here** or you may be solve the problem by yourself! :)

If you have enabled [preload](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293219/is-this-ram-usage-normal), disable it and run from the terminal:

1. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
2. `sudo apt-get autoremove`
3. `sudo apt-get autoclean`
4. `sudo apt-get clean`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Ubuntu 10.04. In my case, there was some conflict between KDE display manager and Gnome Display Manager. I removed KDM, and the problem was solved.

Comment: This seems not to be OP's case, as it was not stated he/she installed another DE.